# Image in HTML not displaying

Tags: html, css, image

I encounter a strange problem. I have two times a similar code to show an image but in one the image shows and in the other it doesn't.

Here is my code :

```
                <div id="blocMethodo">
                    <div id="divTitreMethodo">
                        <p class="texteTitreListeComportements">
                            Notre méthodologie
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divVideoUn">
                        <div class="carteVideoUn">
                            <video autoplay="true" muted loop="true" poster="/Images/Methodologie900.jpg" id="videoDeux">
                                <source src="../Videos/videoprocesssfondgris.mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="divImagePricing">
                        <img src="../Images/Methodologie900.jpg" alt="Methodologie" id="imageMethodo"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="blocPricing">
                    <div id="divTitrePricing">
                        <p class="texteTitreListeComportements">
                            Pricing
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divTextePricing"
                        <p class="premiertexte">
                            Notre tarif s'établit en fonction du nombre de personnes travaillant pour votre organisation.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="divImagePricing">
                        <img src="../Images/Pricingsanstitre900.jpg" alt="Pricing" id="imagePricing"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

and the CSS hereunder

```
#blocMethodo
{
  width: 350px;
  height: 290px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #261939;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#divTitreMethodo
{
  width: 340px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

#imageMethodo
{
  max-width: 100%;
}

#blocPricing
{
  width: 350px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #261939;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#divTitrePricing
{
  width: 340px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#divTextePricing
{
  width: 340px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.divImagePricing
{
  width: 340px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#imagePricing
{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

with all the

> 'video' Div (divVideoUn, carteVideoUn, videoDeux)set to display: none;

because I am in the "smartphone" part of my css.

My problem is that in the first block the image Methodologie900.jpg doesn't show and I only see the yellow rectangle (background of the divImagePricing class). The second image shows perfectly although it is according to me me the same code.
Of course I checked the presence, the extension and the spelling of my image and I even copied/pasted the link Pricingsanstitre900.jpg in place of the link of first image but it didn't help.

Comment: could you share your whole page source code

Comment: The page is very long... but both blocks (blockMethodo and blockPrincing) are in the same div/container (a flex column oriented).

Comment: have you tried launching web page in different browser it could be a cache issue

Comment: It is on a mobile but each time I delete the cache and history of the browser. Doesn't help :-(

Answer (score 0):

On the "#blocmethodo" replace this line:

`height: 290px;`

with this

`min-height: 456px;`

Comment: I did it but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

the `<img src="../Images/Methodologie900.jpg" alt="Methodologie" id="imageMethodo"/>` and the `<img src="../Images/Pricingsanstitre900.jpg" alt="Pricing" id="imagePricing"/>` doesn't have to get the `../` at the beginning of the `src`

Comment: Thanks,
I tried suppressing the ../ but it doesn't help (and it works perfectly for the ../Images/Pricingsanstitre900.jpg.

Comment: My problem is that for <img src="../Images/Pricingsanstitre900.jpg" alt="Pricing" id="imagePricing"/> it works perfectly and for <img src="../Images/Methodologie900.jpg" alt="Methodologie" id="imageMethodo"/> it doesn't...

Comment: Maybe you can try to check if the pictures are in the folder named "Images" and not in the main folder. if so, check if you wrote the name of the folder & images' names right.

Comment: Daniel, I checked... it works for one image and not for the other...

Comment: Maybe the problem is the ending of the picture (I mean maybe it's .png or .jpeg and not .png). Can you check it, please?

Comment: Try to use this: [code](https://jsfiddle.net/_DaNiEl_/b18rLq5y/1/).
Copy the code to your code and run. This should work.

Comment: Daniel,
I solved the problem by adding a display: block; in the class divImagePricing.
I must confess I don't understand why it works now...
Thanks for your time and your help !

Comment: The code I sent is just to fix some errors you had in your code (like no-tag closes to the <p> tag and there weren't spaces between some of the commands and the settings of the commands CSS. I'm glad you solved your problem!